# How to use if/else condition if the content is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

I'm having an issue with my `if`/`else` condition to check if the text is present on the page. If not, it should print "failed".

```
visit "http://stackoverflow.com/"
if page.should have_content('stackoverflow') == true
 print " Passed \r\n"
else
 print " Failed \r\n"
end
```

When it is true, print "Passed" and if false it should print "Failed".

Comment: You are already asserting(`page.should`), why do you need the conditional?

Answer (score 2):

`page.should have_content('stackoverflow')` is an expectation - it will throw an error (`RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError`) if it fails. If you want a condition, you should use [`has_content?`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_text%3F-instance_method):

```
visit "http://stackoverflow.com/"
if page.has_content?('stackoverflow') == true
 print " Passed \r\n"
else
 print " Failed \r\n"
end
```

Comment: Beware when you use `has_content?` like this – if the content is not on the page, I believe Capybara will wait for its timeout interval (several seconds) before returning false. More reading: http://blog.codeship.com/faster-rails-tests/ This might be desired behavior in this case, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked for me, but is there any better way of doing it?

```
if page.has_text?('stackoverflow')
  print " Passed \r\n"
else
  print " Failed \r\n"
end
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's another question that should be part of your original question.